# Why implicit conversion works from derived to base in exception handling?

Tags: c++, oop

I learnt that implicit conversion is not performed in exception handling like from `float` to `int` or `char` to `int` etc. But when i applied the same logic, when asked in interview, for polymorphic class they said that's wrong. So here is the snippet i tried to cross check and its really wrong.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
    virtual void what()
    {
        cout<<"caught in base"<<endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void what()
    {
        cout<<"caught in derived"<<endl;
    }
};

void f()
{
    throw derived(); // throwing instance of derived
}

void fprim()
{
    throw 10.20f; // throwing float
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch(base b)
    {
        cout<<"in base catch"<<endl;
        b.what();
    }
    catch(derived d) // supposed to caught here
    {
        cout<<"in derived catch"<<endl; 
        d.what();
    }


    // worked perfectly fir primitive 
    try
    {
        fprim();
    }
    catch(int i)
    {
        cout<<"in int catch"<<endl;
    }
    catch(float f) 
    {
        cout<<"in float catch"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
in base catch
caught in base
in float catch
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

i was expecting the first line in output should form derived catch statement.

So could some one tell me why and how i implicit conversion works here?

Comment: There is no conversion - a derived type is a base type. Also, you should normally catch via const references.

Comment: What Neil said. That's just how C++ works.  Swap the order of your catch clauses such that `catch(derived d)` goes before `catch(base b)`.

Comment: @selbie but why it didn't go for derived catch as it is there.

Comment: Catch statements are processed in the order they appear in the code, so the base catch is executed, because a derived is a base.

Comment: Note that the base class case is specifically mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch), it's not a general purpose implicit conversion like arithmetic conversion or integral promotion.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions

Comment: @NeilButterworth Thank you for clarifying. And your intention to suggest const reference is to avoid [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), right?

Answer (score 0):

It is specially pointed out that a handler of base class is allowed to handle exception of derived class.

Quoted from [except.handle]/3:

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
>
> - The handler is of type cv T or cv T& and E and T are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), or
> - **the handler is of type cv T or cv T& and T is an unambiguous public base class of E**, or
> - the handler is of type cv T or const T& where T is a pointer or pointer-to-member type and E is a pointer or pointer-to-member type that can be converted to T by one or more of
>
>   - a standard pointer conversion not involving conversions to pointers to private or protected or ambiguous classes
>   - a function pointer conversion
>   - a qualification conversion, or
> - the handler is of type cv T or const T& where T is a pointer or pointer-to-member type and E is std​::​nullptr_­t.